How to enter through ASAP Utilities pop up after running
I have some vba code to run through a couple of ASAP functions. From the Sheets tab I use 8. Split the data into multiple worksheets and the 9. Export worksheets as separate files. What is happening after 9 is a pop up notification telling me 9 has completed. I want to close that pop up and are having trouble doing so.

Here is my code. I have tried multiple variations of the below Send.keys. Even placing them before and after the
Application.Run "'ASAP Utilities x64.xlam'!ASAPRunProc", 233"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.SendKeys "%o"
SendKeys (" ")

Even added
ScreenUpdating = False
Display Alerts= False

Im at a lost and need help
Here is my code
    Sub ASAPutilities()
    With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False                'Turns of alerts
    .AlertBeforeOverwriting = False       'Turns off overwrite alerts
    .ScreenUpdating = False               'Turns off screen updatingEnd With
    End With

    SendKeys "{tab}"    ' activate insert after field
    SendKeys "{tab}"    ' activate insert after field
    SendKeys "{tab}"    ' activate insert after field
    SendKeys (" ")      ' press space bar
    SendKeys "%o"       ' press the OK button

    Application.Run "'ASAP Utilities x64.xlam'!ASAPRunProc", 233

    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    SendKeys (" ")
    SendKeys "%o"

    With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True                 'Turns back on alerts
    .AlertBeforeOverwriting = True        'Turns on Overwrite alerts
    .ScreenUpdating = True                'Turns on screen updating
    End With

    End Sub

